# flutter making if statement outside the class

Tags: class, if-statement, flutter, code-reuse

hello everyone i am creating a flutter app and i need to do a simple if statement to decide the 
device type
i can do it inside the original class like this and it will work fine of course

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    double font;
    double categoriesFont;
    double navHeight;
    double navIcons;
    if(DeviceInformation(context).width > 600){
      font = fontTablet;
      categoriesFont = categoriesTabletFont;
      navHeight = navTabletHeight;
      navIcons = navTabletIcons;
    }else{
      font = fontPhone;
      categoriesFont = categoriesPhoneFont;
      navHeight = navPhoneHeight;
      navIcons = navPhoneIcons;
    }

    return Scaffold(....
```

but instead of putting this code in every page i have, i want to make a class that will do this if statement and it will return font , categoriesFont , navHeight and navIcons variables so that i can use them as much as i need in other pages

i want to do something like this

```
//this class decides device type and use its corresponding percentages
class SetDeviceType{
  final context;
  SetDeviceType(this.context);
  double font;
  double categoriesFont;
  double navHeight;
  double navIcons;
  void deviceType(){
    if(DeviceInformation(context).width > 600){
      font = fontTablet;
      categoriesFont = categoriesTabletFont;
      navHeight = navTabletHeight;
      navIcons = navTabletIcons;
    }else{
      font = fontPhone;
      categoriesFont = categoriesPhoneFont;
      navHeight = navPhoneHeight;
      navIcons = navPhoneIcons;
    }
  }
  double get responsiveFont => font;
  double get responsiveCategoriesFont => categoriesFont;
  double get responsiveNavHeight => navHeight;
  double get responsiveNavIcons => navIcons;

}
```

and then simply i can do

```
DeviceType(context).font
```

to get the font variable after deciding the device screen type and use it, but i didn't find a way around it.

the main idea here is to make this if statement reusable and to make the code cleaner.

any idea how i can make this happen ? it doesn't have to be a class anything will do the job is welcome i.e function, etc

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want a class that you can reuse to provide different values depending on the width of the device.

I think your solution was pretty close. You can use a constructor with a body, and there you can make the conditional assignment. Like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DeviceInformation{

  //These fields are just some dummy values i used to test this
  //You can have these values wherever 
  static const fontTablet = 2.0;
  static const categoriesTabletFont = 2.0;
  static const navTabletHeight = 2.0;
  static const navTabletIcons = 2.0;
  static const fontPhone = 1.0;
  static const categoriesPhoneFont = 1.0;
  static const navPhoneHeight = 1.0;
  static const navPhoneIcons = 1.0;
  
  double _font;
  double _categoriesFont;
  double _navHeight;
  double _navIcons;
  
  double get responsiveFont => _font;
  double get responsiveCategoriesFont => _categoriesFont;
  double get responsiveNavHeight => _navHeight;
  double get responsiveNavIcons => _navIcons;
  
  DeviceInformation(BuildContext context){
  //This gives me the display width
  //Context.size.width would throw an error because
  //the widget's size hasn't been calculated at this point
  if(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 600){
      _font = fontTablet;
      _categoriesFont = categoriesTabletFont;
      _navHeight = navTabletHeight;
      _navIcons = navTabletIcons;
    }else{
      _font = fontPhone;
      _categoriesFont = categoriesPhoneFont;
      _navHeight = navPhoneHeight;
      _navIcons = navPhoneIcons;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can just call it from build

```
class _MyHomePageState  extends State<MyHomePage>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    DeviceInformation deviceInfo = DeviceInformation(context);
    
    return Text('${deviceInfo.responsiveFont}');
  }
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for :D

Comment: Thank you very much this was exactly the idea the missing chain part was the constructor *_^ it worked perfectly thanks a lot. i would like to ask you I know how to use classes and state full widgets to build apps but i don't have a deep understanding about them can you please refer a book or a website for me to understand each part of flutter like classes , state full , stateless , flutter mechanism and thats kind of stuff ?

Comment: @RYOKSecurity Honestly I'm not sure where to refer you to.. I still don't have a deep understanding of a lot of things and everything is making more and more sense as I go. That said, the videos 4-8 of this series by the flutter team [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjxrf2q8roU2HdJQDjJzOeO6J3FoFLWr2) focuses on widgets. Maybe it could help you. Also, I've found that the flutter api docs can provide a better understanding of many elements(although sometimes it can be a bit confusing).

Comment: Thank you very much brother  i honestly appreciate it ^_^